# Wait for an observable to return to make another request

Tags: angular, typescript, http, asynchronous, angular-ng-if

I'm grabbing data from the studio ghibli api, and I was wondering if there was any way I could wait for a get request to return, use an array from the returned data to make another request.

Check out this stackblitz link, click on Princess Mononoke in the nav or the image, and look into the film component. Not all films have api data attached for this specific data return, so just scroll down to that film. How can I wait for the api request to return to make another api call? I want to pull all the individual people within that film into the film component\

Stackblitz link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/film-people-api-error-w2kbrr?file=src/app/film/film.component.html

Comment: Have you tried mergeMap?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `mergeMap` or just put the latter set of requests in the first
subscription i.e.

```js
// First set
this.api.getFilm(this.film).subscribe((data) => {
    
    this.filmData = data[0];
    console.log('Here is the data returned from the ghibli api', data);
    
    // Second set
    for (let i = 0; i < this.filmData.people.length; i++) {
        this.api.getPeople(this.filmData.people[i]).subscribe((data) => {
            this.people.push(data[0]);
        });
    }

});
```